# MYSQL get status topic for show static pages or normal page

Tags: php, mysql

in this below sql commands i want to add option to choice which topics must be show normal posts or static pages ?

in setting table i have default_front_page to change this option. if this filed is not 0 sql commad must be fetch static page

`default_front_page` is static page id and i.id is topic id.

all posts such as normal or static pages seved into contents table and i can use with post_type filed to guess this post is normal or static.whats my problem in this code now?

```
SELECT 
     SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS i.* , 
     c.title AS category_name, 
     u.name, 
     u.family, 
     i.thumb_image,
     CONCAT( u.name, ' ', u.family ) AS author,
     tumbnail_image_width,
     tumbnail_image_height,
     CASE (s.sortable)
        WHEN 3 THEN 100000000 - i.id 
        WHEN 2 THEN i.date_time
        WHEN 1 THEN i.order_display
     END  AS SortField
  FROM   contents i
  JOIN   categories c ON c.id = i.category
  JOIN   users u ON u.id = i.posted_by
  JOIN   settings s ON s.portal = i.portal
  WHERE 
         i.portal = '{$portal_id}'
         AND CASE WHEN post_type = 4
              THEN date(NOW()) BETWEEN i.from_dateTime AND i.to_dateTime 
         ELSE post_type = 1
         END
  AND i.t_status = 1 AND 
         CASE WHEN s.default_front_page <> 0 
              THEN i.id = s.default_front_page
         END 
  ORDER BY SortField                  
  LIMIT {$portalSettings['display_post_count']};
```

Comment: Case doesn't work like that.

Comment: @JakubKania, how to fix this problem? can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `CASE` in the `WHERE` clause. `AND` and `OR` should do it:

```
WHERE 
     i.portal = '{$portal_id}'
     AND (
           (post_type = 4 
             AND date(NOW()) BETWEEN i.from_dateTime AND i.to_dateTime
           )
           OR post_type = 1
         )         
     AND i.t_status = 1 
     AND (s.default_front_page = 0 OR i.id = s.default_front_page)
```